# How do I search a map in Java for a key that matches a predicate?

Tags: java, java-8

Do I understand this correctly? Is this how Java developers do it? Or is there a better way?

So if I want to find a key in a map that matches a predicate, I must first get the key set from the map through the conveniently supplied method. THEN, I have to convert the set into a stream through the conveniently supplied method. THEN, I have to filter the stream with my predicate through the conveniently supplied method. THEN, I have to convert the stream into a container of a type of my choosing, possibly supplying a collector to do so, through the conveniently supplied method. THEN, I can at least check the container for empty to know if anything matched. Only then can I use the key(s) to extract the values of interest, or I could have used the entry set from the beginning and spare myself the extra step.

Is this the way, really? Because as far as I can tell, there are no other methods either built into the map or provided as a generic search algorithm over iterators or some other container abstraction.

Comment: Can you provide an example (written in Java) covering your use-case/grievances?

Comment: *Why* would you be using a predicate to lookup in a map? You're not using the map, but relying on sequential search, so why is it a map in the first place, if you're going to use a predicate? Your premise seems flawed.

Comment: basically, yeah. That's pretty easy, though: `map.keySet().stream().filter(key -> <your condition here>).findFirst();` that gets you an `Optional`, you can test if it is empty, then use the key if not. (or simply get the value and catch the exception).

Comment: @njzk2 You could then lookup the value using the `Optional.map()` method. Alternatively, use `entrySet()`, and you have it all.

Comment: Does that `map.forEach((k, v) -> { if (predicate(k)) { action(v); }});` cover your use case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a nutshell, it is as simple as:

```
Predicate<T> predicate = (t -> <your predicate here>);
return myMap.keySet()
    .stream()
    .filter(predicate)
    .findAny()
    .map(myMap::get);
```

returns an empty Optional if no key matches

(nota: `findAny` is better than `findFirst` because it does not prevent parallelization if relevant, and `findFirst` is useless anyway since the `Set` of keys is not sorted in any meaningful way, unless your `Map` is a `SortedMap`)

Comment: Once I have an Optional<> how do I cast it to a map entry type? I'm getting a warning about an unchecked cast.

Comment: the optional holds the key. That's what the `map(...)` does, it optionally calls `get` on your map to get the value.

Comment: It’s not correct to assume that a map’s key set has no order. This obviously depends on the map’s type, e.g. `SortMap`s have an ordering and so has `LinkedHashMap`. The good news is that the stream *knows* when it has no intrinsic order, so in these cases `findFirst` is as good as `findAny`, not hindering performance. So the reason to use `findAny` should not be the assumption that there is no ordering anyway, but the *intention* to get an arbitrary match rather than the first.

Comment: @Holger in this case, `findFirst` would express specific knowledge on the structure of the map. If the map is declared as `SortedMap` that's fine, if it's declared simply as `Map`, it's an assumption that may not hold in the future.

Comment: It’s the other way round. If you don’t know whether the input has a meaningful order, use `findFirst`, unless you know that it is not relevant to use the first match for your particular task. It’s your explanation in the answer containing a specific assumption about the source. As said, if the the input has no meaningful order, the stream already knows that and can use an unordered operation even if you use `findFirst` (of course, whether it actually exploits that property, is implementation dependent).

Comment: @Holger which means that it is going to behave differently depending on if the input has or has not a meaningful order, which can change without your knowledge, if your function accepts a `Map`. Meaning that what used to be a fast un-ordered operation becomes a slow ordered operation because whoever calls your function decided that `TreeMap` was more fitting for whatever other thing they were doing

Comment: As said, whether “first” is relevant, depends on the *semantics of your particular task*. If your task demands using the first (if the input has a meaningful order), then you have to use it, even if that could imply performance drawbacks. If your task does not require the first, you should use “any”, to document the intention, even if it makes no actual performance difference with the current implementation. Don’t discuss performance, where semantics matters. Anyway, `findFirst()` does *not* prevent parallelism, the actual differences are tiny.

Comment: that's exactly what I'm trying to say. If you need the _first_ item, use `findFirst`, but then you need to express that you need something that can give you a significant _first_, e.g. by requiring a `SortedMap` in your signature.

Answer (score 12):

I prefer `entrySet` myself as well. You should find this efficient:

```
Map<String, Integer> map; //Some example Map
//The map is filled here

List<Integer> valuesOfInterest = map.entrySet()
                                 .stream() //Or parallelStream for big maps
                                 .filter(e -> e.getKey().startsWith("word")) //Or some predicate
                                 .map(Map.Entry::getValue) //Get the values
                                 .collect(Collectors.toList()); //Put them in a list
```

The list is empty if nothing matched. This is useful if multiple keys match the predicate.

Comment: nice! note that all entries are always browsed, no matter how many match the predicate.

Answer (score 1):

It’s not clear why you are shouting “THEN” so often. It’s the standard way of solving problems, to combine tools designed for broad variety of use cases to get your specific result. There is a built-in capability for traversing a sequence of elements and search for matches, the Stream API. Further, the `Map` interface provides you with the Collection views, `keySet()`, `entrySet()`, and `values()`, to be able to use arbitrary tools operating on Collections, the bridge to the Stream API being one of them.

So if you have a `Map<Key,Value>` and are interested in the values, whose keys match a predicate, you may use

```
List<Value> valuesOfInterest = map.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(e -> e.getKey().fulfillsCondition())
    .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

which consists of three main steps, `filter` to select matches, `map` to specify whether you are interested in the key, value, entry or a converted value of each matche and `collect(Collectors.toList())` to specify that you want to collect the results into a `List`.

Each of these steps could be replaced by a different choice and the entire stream pipeline could be augmented by additional processing steps. Since you want this specific combination of operations, there is nothing wrong with having to specify exactly these three steps instead of getting a convenience method for your specific use case.

The initial step of `entrySet().stream()` is required as you have to select the entry set as starting point and switch to the Stream API which is the dedicated API for element processing that doesn’t modify the source. The Collection API, on the other hand, provides you with methods with might mutate the source. If you are willing to use that, the alternative to the code above is

```
map.keySet().removeIf(key -> !key.fulfillsCondition());
Collection<Value> valuesOfInterest=map.values();
```

which differs in that the nonmatching entries are indeed removed from the source map. Surely, you don’t want to confuse these two, so it should be understandable, why there is a clear separation between the Collection API and the Stream API.